# Which approach use when admin can act as some user in application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, identity

The application requires that admin user can provide same actions like real user. It is normal situation when in application changes `IIdentity` so that when we click to button "Login like some user" result is as if this user logins via default login page, but in this `IIdentity` we have property `IsAdminLoginLikeSomeUser` which shows that it is Admin login like some user?

I have second approach when user who is authorized in this situation Admin, when click to button "Login like some user" the admin user stay authorized, but to 
`IIdentity` will be add property `AndminActAsUserId`, which allow admin act like some user.

Application need that Admin can help to some user by acting like some user.

My question:
Which approach is security save? I ask it because feel that first approach is not very good and will be very insecure.

I hope that somebody have an experience and can help me resolve this problem.

Comment: Search for "impersonation".

Answer (score 2):

### Security

From a *security* standpoint, the best practices regarding prevention of users somehow retrieving sensitive information in the server memory is always applicable.  This includes showing a list of all users to impersonate *before* the user in question has been authenticated.  Otherwise, there is no best approach here.

### Architecture

From an architecture standpoint, it makes sense that you continue to use `IIdentity` throughout your program as you did before without having to check a "IsAdminLoginLikeSomeUser" property, so you should focus on this as it requires the least amount of change to be performed on your web application.

### Implementation

What the changes ultimately amounts to is validating credentials of the user as you always would.  A normal user is authenticated as it is and an admin is authenticated as it is.  The difference lies in the fact that in *addition to* the normal credentials, an admin can also login as a different user.  Since you wouldn't want any and all users to see the list of existing users, this should be a post-signin operation (admin is already authenticated).

### Usage

The moment the admin chooses to sign-in as another user, you should treat it as a second signin.  The class that implements `IIdentity` should be replaced with another for this special case that does nothing other than encapsulate the admin user and the user to imitate.  For anything concerning permissions, you return the results from the user to imitate.  If name or user data is requested, you can return the results from the admin user.  Don't forget to refresh the page client-side afterwards to potentially alter the page to show what the user would see with his or her permissions!

You shouldn't need to ever know if current user is administrator pretending to be another user throughout your program and essentially, this aspect is transparent to the rest of your program if done properly.

Answer (score 1):

From a security point of view, and without any other technical measures, none of this approach is good. Both:

- fail to implement segregation of duties,
- allow the admin to perform actions that he is not entitled to do
- allows admin to impersonate a user
- fail to provide a reliable audit trial of who did what
- provides a highway for hackers to misuse the system if they manage to get admin's password.

If this is for a mission critical or for a financial system, this would be unacceptable.

You can however with additional code address these different issues, for example by extending the logging and audit trail so that actions on behalf are systematically identified, and by informing the user of actions made on his/her behalf.

Eventually you could also add a support request button for the user, so that admin can only intervene for the few users having a request indicator activated.

You second approach seems more promising in this regard. I understand that in this scenario, the admin is considered as himself and that the acting on behalf will work only if the authorisation check code is able to cope with the on-behalf use case, whereas the first approach would immediately be an open door, even for functions which were not yet updated with the extra security logic.